# Compilation Order Of Files In a scala Project

Tags: scala, compilation, dependencies, topological-sort

Hi I am trying to identify and generate the compilation order of files in my scala project, the dependencies between files or topological graph of my source files? How can I get this done?

Comment: Why do you need this? Normally one is not supposed to rely on compilation order of files. Normally compilation order of subprojects is enough.

Comment: Suppose you have file `A.scala` with content `class A { new B }` and file `B.scala` with content `class B { new A }`. What compilation order do you expect?

Comment: I don’t expect an order, a cyclic graph would do. Or a noncylic with an a presumed order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile all files that may have dependencies between them together: To figure out what file depends on what, you need to know what symbols a file refers to, and what symbols are in each file. To do those things, you need to compile the files.

In other words, you won't know what's in a file until you compile it, and you won't know whether you can compile it independently until you know what's in it.

For incremental compilation, for each file you need to store what symbols are defined in what file, then if a file is edited and re-compiled, you need to recursively re-compile all files that referred to symbols in the file.

Comment: According to what you say , is there a way to create a dependency graph for compilation of a single source file?

Comment: @PheniXTylor For example you can use [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) to parse your source files and analyze trees of your programs. If you switch [SemanticDB](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html) on you can see what symbols are used in  what places.

Comment: I see what you are saying I started doing that, but someone must have already done it I assume, do you know such a project?

Comment: Without scalameta, you could look at the acyclic compiler plugin: https://github.com/lihaoyi/acyclic -- regardless, whether you go with SemanticDB or a compiler plugin, you will have to compile the files first.